# C# screensaver: configuration dialog modal to provided HWND

Tags: c#, configuration, modal-dialog, screensaver

I am working on a C# XNA screensaver kit and so far, everything is in place except for the configuration dialog which must be modal to the *Screen Saver Settings* dialog provided by windows ("/c:<hwnd>" argument).

My benchmark is Vistas builtin *3D Text* screensaver - my code shall provide the same features and regarding the configuration dialog, *3D Text* displays fully modal to the *Screen Saver Settings* dialog and when clicking *Screen Saver Settings* dialog, the dialogs blink without accepting the click.

I have tried the method of wrapping the HWND with a IWin32Window as suggested by [Ryan Farley](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/03/23/465.aspx), but even though my dialog displays on top of the *Screen Saver Settings* dialog, the controls in *Screen Saver Settings* dialog still can be clicked.

So do I need some exotic Win32API calls to inform the parent dialog that it has been modalized or does a more clean solution exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turned out that the `HWND` provided by windows to the screensaver is a child of the settings dialog, so by calling `GetParent` on the `HWND`, I get an `HWND` that represents the dialog.

Today is the day that I wrote my first question on stackoverflow.com and answered the first question.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the [`SetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function.

Comment: I am already using SetParent, but I have now discovered that the HWND provided by windows to the screensaver is a child of the settings dialog, so by calling GetParent on the HWND, I get a HWND that represents the dialog.

Comment: Yes it does. My configuration dialog is fully modal to the windows screensaver settings dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Additionally I was not able to directly hook a dialog to a foreign window with .NET. Therefore I supply a work around to hook a dialog to the parent of a given window handle:

```
public class CHelpWindow : Form
{ // this class hooks to a foreign window handle and then it starts a
  // modal dialog to this form; .NET seems not to be able to hook a dialog 
  // to a foreign window handle directly: therefore this solution

  // retrieves the parent window of the passed child
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr GetParent (IntPtr hWndChild);

  // changes the parent window of the passed child
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr SetParent
    (IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  public CHelpWindow (long liHandle)
  // this constructor initializes this form and hooks this form to the parent
  // of the passed window handle; then it prepares the call to create the
  // dialog after this form window is first shown in the screen.
  {
    // removing the system title of the window
    FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    // the dialog will be created when this form is first shown
    Shown += new EventHandler (HelpWindow_Shown);

    // hooking to the parent of the passed handle: that is the control, not
    // the tab of the screen saver dialog
    IntPtr oParent = GetParent (new IntPtr (liHandle));
    SetParent (Handle, oParent);
  }

  // --------------------------------------------------------------------
  private void HelpWindow_Shown (object oSender, EventArgs oEventArgs)
  // this function is called when the form is first shown; now is the right
  // time to start our configuration dialog
  {
    // positioning this window outside the parent area
    Location   = new Point (-100, -100);
    // reducing the size
    Size       = new Size (1, 1);
    ClientSize = new Size (1, 1);
    // creating the dialog
    CKonfiguration oConfiguration = new CKonfiguration ();
    // starting this dialog with the owner of this object; because this
    // form is hooked to the screen saver dialog, the startet dialog is
    // then indirectly hooked to that dialog
    oConfiguration.ShowDialog (this);
    // we don not need this object any longer
    Close ();
  }
}
```

After extracting your handle from the command line

```
/c:####
```

you create your Dialog by

```
CHelpWindow oHelpWindow = new CHelpWindow (liHandle);
oHelpWindow.ShowDialog ();
```

Reimer